# I have a problem array.map() method it loops so many times every time i call that in React

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

What I am trying to do is I want to store every pressed key into an array

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

let App = () => {


let [check, setCheck] = useState([])

document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    let eve = e.key
    setCheck(prevValues => [...prevValues, eve])
    // console.log(check)
})



return (
    <div>
        <h1>
            {check.map(item => {
                return <h1>{item}</h1>
            })}
        </h1>
        
        <h1>{'test text'}</h1>
    </div>
)}

export default App
```

if I press 'a' it returns 'a' on the page but if I press "a" again it shows "aaa" on the page and if I do this again it will return "aaaaaaa" why is this happening i just pressed 3 times but it looped 7 times.
Just why is it happening? what's missing

this image is an example of what is happening I just pressed a key 3 times and it returns and assigned so many times

Take a look at my problem thanks

Comment: Every time the component re-renders it's adding another keypress event listener to the DOM.  You need to remove the listener before re-rendering, or else check to see if a listener already exists before adding a redundant one.

Comment: there was no listener except this thank you for seeing my question

Comment: Aaaaaaaa is a clear sign that pleasure is being offered by you, so be proud if yourself. Well done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your component renders your function is executed. After the first render you add a eventlistener to the document. When the listener is triggered it calls `setCheck` which will rerender your component. Since rerendering is executing your function (react does this 2 times) another 2 eventListeners are added and you get the result of 'aaa'.

To prevent this you could just create the eventListener once :

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const checkKey = (e) => {
        let eve = e.key
        setCheck(prevValues => [...prevValues, eve])
    }
    document.addEventListener('keypress', checkKey);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', checkKey);
    }
}, []);
```

See the useEffect hook.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful, but I didn't understand how the rerender happened and why the listener executing 2 times. 
Can you please mention a guide to that topic?

Comment: I just mistakenly star that already asked question that is not authentic please ignore that.
The answer I ticked is correct

Comment: so this answer is correct? Asking to decide if upvote or not. You judge, This guy seems cool, looking at his pic. Like the type of guy who could be a friend if from same town. You know?

Comment: I bet we're not from the same town, Aran..